# Request tag creation and synonym

Tags: support, stack-overflow, tags, synonym-request

I find it strange that there is no [ahk](/questions/tagged/ahk) tag, just [autohotkey](/questions/tagged/autohotkey). These are exactly the same thing, so why not? AHK is also much easier to type.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Synonyms are generally made for two *existing and well-established* tags that mean the same thing. For example, [csharp](/questions/tagged/csharp) and [c#](/questions/tagged/c%23) may be synonymed. It is of no use to synonym a nonexistent tag, even when the non-existent one is easier to type. Once it is well-used, the synonymization may be done, but both have to be pretty powerful tags.

With that said, do not spend your time retagging [autohotkey](/questions/tagged/autohotkey) to [ahk](/questions/tagged/ahk). If people use it often, then it will be something that can be brought to the table again. There is also no need to ask for it to be created since IMHO the current tag is fine.

Comment: Hmm. That makes sense. Thanks! I'm going to request that the tag [tag:ahk] be created then. I will accept that answer when SO lets me (10 minutes)

Comment: @PicklishDoorknob: you can't request a tag creation out of the blue. Tags only get created when they are added to questions. Renaming `autohotkey` to `ahk` looks like a *regression* to me.

Comment: I just want to be able to type "ahk" and it to still work.

Comment: @PicklishDoorknob: Creating a new tag because "I want to type less" is not the answer to your problem. You'd only spam our tag system with *one more* useless tag that really doesn't belong there. It would likely get destroyed by the Tag Deletionist Cabal (or whatever it's called).

Comment: Well... use autohotkey, I heard it does keyboard shortcuts :) Or type 'otk' an you'll get it as the first suggestion., @PicklishDoorknob

Answer (score 3):

Tag synonyms are not used as a shortcut for the main tag; they are used when users keep using two different tags for the same purpose. Suppose that enough users use [drupal7](/questions/tagged/drupal7) instead of [drupal-7](/questions/tagged/drupal-7); if [drupal7](/questions/tagged/drupal7) is continuously used, and it is rather impossible to re-tag the questions using it because there is always somebody using it in new questions, then [drupal7](/questions/tagged/drupal7) is merged with [drupal-7](/questions/tagged/drupal-7), and made a synonym of [drupal-7](/questions/tagged/drupal-7).

Making a tag synonym of a longer one doesn't make sense. First off, there isn't the need to completely write a tag as there is autocomplete that suggests you the tags that you probably want to use. Secondly, some tags could be used as short version of more than one tag; it would be rather difficult to decide for which tag it should be a synonym.

[image: screenshot]

[image: screenshot]

[image: screenshot]

The second screenshot proves what [Mat](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/158667/mat) said in [his comment](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/155292/request-tag-creation-and-synonym/155295#comment446137_155293): Write *otk* when you are adding a tag to a question, and you will get *autohotkey* as first suggestion.
Keep in mind that the first suggested tag is the one matching the string you entered, and which is the most used one. In the case [hotkey](/questions/tagged/hotkey) is used in more questions than [autohotkey](/questions/tagged/autohotkey), [hotkey](/questions/tagged/hotkey) would be the first suggested tag.

As you notice in the last screenshot, [drupal7](/questions/tagged/drupal7) has been really merged with [drupal-7](/questions/tagged/drupal-7), and made its synonym, but it didn't happen because [drupal7](/questions/tagged/drupal7) was a shortcut for [drupal-7](/questions/tagged/drupal-7). In fact, by the time you write drupal7, you could also write drupal-7.